# DAX - Filter function with Earlier and "Non-Earlier" condition together

Tags: function, filter, powerbi, powerpivot, dax

I would like to know why this formula does fetch the results I want.

I have a table with:

```
customer_id | date_booking | booking_status | salon_id |
```

I want to check if a certain booking of a customer is the first or not, where
its considered a successful booking if booking_status = 8 or 14

My Calculated Column was:

```
If(Calculate(Min(date_booking);filter(table; booking_status = 8 ||
booking_status = 14);filter(table;customer_id = earlier(customer_id);
filter(table;salon_id = earlier(salon_id)))=date_booking;1;0)
```

Unfortunately the booking_status condition fails here.

Comment: What is the context where you want to know if the booking was successful or not? It would be useful If you edit your question include your expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create a calculated column like this:

```
IF (
    [date_booking]
        = CALCULATE (
            MIN ( [date_booking] );
            FILTER (
                ALL ( 'Table' );
                [customer_id] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[customer_id] )
                && [salon_id] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[salon_id] )
                    && ( [booking_status] = 8
                    || [booking_status] = 14 )
            )
        );
    1;
    0
)
```

It will put `1` if the booking was the first with successful status, otherwise `0`.

Comment: Thanks for replying !
Tomorrow I will try it out and let you guys know!

Comment: @LuisDoCantoBrum, you are welcome. If my answer solved your issue you can [mark it as the correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to positively close the question.

Answer (score 0):

May be the second filter you add erase the previous filter because CALCULATE can alter the filter context. Since you working on one table and change the filter of just one table try to use only one filter. Look as your modified code below..!

```
IF(
    CALCULATE(MIN(date_booking);
        FILTER(table; 
            booking_status = 8 || booking_status = 14 AND 
            customer_id = EARLIER(customer_id) AND
            salon_id = earlier(salon_id)))=date_booking;
    1;0)
```

I don't know if the code works or not because **I'm not test the code**. Every time you write dax code, always pay attention to what context the formula are working on, where you write your dax code..? is it a measure or a calculated column..? Measure will work on filter context where calculated column on row context.

Comment: Hey Cheries, sorry I should have stated that it was a calculated column!
I will give it a go on that one tomorrow

Comment: This also did the job! Thank you!